# How to use grok patterns to match this logs?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

The log content like this:

```
[2018-07-09 11:30:59] [13968] [INFO] [1e74b6b7-fcb2-4dde-a259-7db1de0350ea] run entry() 11ms
[2018-07-09 11:30:59] [13968] [INFO] [1e74b6b7-fcb2-4dde-a259-7db1de0350ea] entry done
```

The first line logged function call info with exec time, other line is normal log.

Now, I want to match all of them, and if there is exec time in the line, I want to match it.

I write grok pattern like this:

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{NUMBER:process_id}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] \[%{UUID:request_id}\] %{DATA:message}(\s%{NUMBER:use_time}ms)?
```

it dose not work. The match result is:

```
{
  "process_id": "13968",
  "loglevel": "INFO",
  "message": "",
  "request_id": "1e74b6b7-fcb2-4dde-a259-7db1de0350ea",
  "timestamp": "2018-07-09 11:30:59"
}
```

if change DATA:message to GREEDYDATA:message, it can not match exec time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using raw regexp to replace total message field:

`\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{NUMBER:process_id}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] \[%{UUID:request_id}\] (?<message>.+ (?:(?<use_time>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)ms)?.*)`

Comment: my pattern cant match just one word, others test is ok